# Enhanced for loop unable to initialize object

Tags: java, for-loop

```
protected Day[] days= new Day[n];
for(int i=0;i<days.length; i++)
{
    days[i]= new Day(5);
}
```

Above mentioned code works fine for me but modified for loop as mentioned below results in NullPointerException when I try to access the elements of the array. Can anyone explain why does it happens?

```
protected Day[] days= new Day[n];
for(Day d:days)
{
    d= new Day(5);
}
```

Comment: You can't do that. `d` is the contents of the cell. You can't assign to it; it's just a copy. I don't know why it would cause a NPE though.

Comment: You can assign to it, it just won't affect anything.

Comment: I don't see why you would have a NullPointerException. It should do no change on `days` in the loop as @Oliver Charlesworth said. Can you show the stacktrace ?

Comment: @davidxxx They probably got a NullPointerException when they tried to run things on objects they thought were actually in the array.

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest Maybe. But in this case it is not a reproducible problem for us.

Comment: @davidxxx It resulted in NPE when I tried to access the element which I was expecting to be in the array.

Comment: @MohammadAmir you get an NPE because you deleted the for loop with a local control variable `i` and use the foreach loop which do not really assign value to the array of days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Java sees the enhanced for loop that you've made, it runs whatever you put inside it and makes a new variable (called `d`) and gives this variable a value of whatever is inside of your array. When you set `d` equal to a `new Day(5);` you are changing the value of the variable `d`, not the value inside the array. Here is a workaround:

```
protected D[] days = new Day [n];
for(int i = 0;i<days.length;i++)
   days[i] = new Day(5);
```

This reaches into the actual array to set values. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Loop variable in enhanced `for` loop is temporary. Assigning it inside loop body has no effect on the original item. Here is what happens to the loop according to Java Language Specification:

> ```
> Day[] days = ...
> for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
>      Day d = days[i];
>      ...
> }
> ```

When you assign `d`, it changes the local variable `d`, not `days[i]`, which isnearly always an error. For that reason, some programming shops adopt a practice of making loop variable of enhanced `for` loop final:

```
for(final Day d:days) {
    d= new Day(5); // <<== Compile-time error
}
```

If you want to shorten the code by avoiding the loop, use

```
Arrays.setAll(days, i -> new Day(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Second type of `for` uses `Iterator` for iterating by elements. Initializing reference `d` makes no sence, because this operation doesn't change reference inside your array.